# Estrutura condicional sucinta com múltiplas comparações

Tags: php, java

Como comparar três itens com o mesmo resultado?
Estou atualmente fazendo da forma que se segue, só que assim o design do código não fica elegante.

```
if ($title == 0 && $squad == 0 && $level == 0) {
   return true;
}
```

O que eu estou querendo é algo como:

```
if ($title && $squad && $level == 0) {
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Tente `$title == $squad && $title == $level`

Comment: Já vi esse tipo de comparação, mas não quero algo assim. EU quero da forma que eu descrevi a cima @ValdeirPsr

Comment: Você não pode ter mais de duas condições. O PHP vai gerar o erro *T_IS_EQUAL*.

Comment: A forma sugerida por @ValdeirPsr pode falhar caso `$title` seja diferente de `0`. Caso queira usar assim, pode adicionar a validação de `$title == 0`

Comment: Não compreendi @rLinhares

Comment: Estou entendendo que as três variáveis precisam ser iguais a `0`. Se sim, você pode comparar como @ValdeirPsr sugeriu (isso será verdadeiros se todas forem 0, 1, 2 ou qualquer valor) e adicionar o que coloquei, garantindo que seja sempre `0`.

Comment: Só que dá forma que você sugeriu foi apresentado um erro. @rLinhares

Comment: Você pode usar a segunda alternativa? `return $title == $squad == $level == 0;`

Comment: Só que não quero usar isso como retorno. quero usar isso numa estrutura condicional @rLinhares

Comment: tem que ser tudo igual a `0`? ou basta ser igual??

Comment: TUDO IGUAL A ZERO. @rLinhares

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75579/discussion-between-rlinhares-and-ikaro-sales).

Comment: Os valores para as variável são só `0` ou `1`? ou pode ter outros valores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você colocou as tags PHP e Java, então vou dar soluções em ambas as linguagens.

Em PHP:

```php
$t = array_unique(array($title, $squad, $level));
if (count($t) == 1 && in_array(0, $t)) {
    return true;
}
```

Em Java:

```java
Set<Integer> s = Set.of(title, squad, level);
if (s.size() == 1 && s.contains(0)) {
    return true;
}
```

Outro em Java:

```java
if (IntStream.of(title, squad, level).allMatch(x -> x == 0)) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Se o `if` continuar em coisas que não são um `return false`:

```
if (!$a && !$b && !$c) {
   return true;
}

... outros statements ...
```

Alternativa ao código todo da pergunta, em PHP, se for retornar de qq forma:

```
return !$a && !$b && !$c;
```

Mas o "deselegante" é relativo, acho muito pior compacto que não é legível, do que claro como o original.

Só tome cuidado com o PHP. Dependendo do tipo, pois coisas estranhas acontecem, ainda mais quando se "inventa moda".

Nota: como mencionado pelo @rray nos comentários, esta expressão equivale às de cima:

```
if ( !($a || $b || $c) ) ...
```

Comment: `!($a || $b || $c)` seria um equivalente (se eu não me perdi) ?

Comment: @rray pensei nisso também, mas achei que ia ficar esquisito no `if (!(   ... ))`

Answer (score 1):

O nosso amigo Miguel formulou a seguinte resposta, mas por algum motivo ele não quis postar:

```php
<?php

$title = 0;
$squad = 0;
$level = 0;

var_dump([$title, $squad, $level] == [0,0,0]);

$level = 1;

var_dump([$title, $squad, $level] == [0,0,0]);
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/MrRp8p)

Comment: Obgado Victor, estou no telefone e já estava de saída do trabalho e ia ficar sem computador. A tua é deveras melhor

Answer (score 0):

Se for algo constante no projeto, eu recomendaria criar uma função para isso. Inclusive, seria possível, além das sugestões nas outras respostas, utilizar a função [`array_reduce`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-reduce.php):

```
function has_same_value($array, $value) {
    return array_reduce($array, function ($carry, $item) use ($value) {
        return $carry && ($item == $value);
    }, true);
}
```

Assim, bastaria fazer:

```
return has_same_value([$title, $squad, $level], 0);
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/DotingThatRobots) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/fpv5oV)</sup>

Ou ainda:

```
function array_all($array, $callback) {
    foreach($array as $item) {
        if (!$callback($item)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Que se beneficia do curto-circuito de expressões lógicas, parando de iterar no primeiro item falso.

```
$title = 0;
$squad = 0;
$level = 0;

$resultado = array_all([$title, $squad, $level], function ($item) {
    return $item == 0;
});

var_dump($resultado);  // bool(true)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/BumpyAuthorizedUtility) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/omioc6)</sup>